# Understanding output in alloy

Tags: alloy

Cannot understand output of alloy code:

```
abstract sig Name{}
one sig N0, N1, N2 extends Name{}
abstract sig Book{}
one sig b0 extends Book { addr : Name -> Name}
abstract sig E{}
one sig e0 extends E{}
pred show(){
  some *(b0.addr)

}

run show
```

I am curious if the output will contain (e0,e0) and (b0,b0). I have attached the output of the analyzer but dont know how to interpret it. Does it mean that (e0,e0) is in the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `(e0, e0)` being "in the solution"? I'd recommend that you read the Alloy book (Software Abstractions, MIT Press, 2012) for an explanation of all the basic notions.

Comment: I mean does the reflexive and transitive closure *(b0.addr) include the tuple (e0,e0)?